# What is a good strategy to read many button inputs while still doing USB?

Tags: usb, avr, interrupts

I am trying to design a USB joystick with many different buttons. The board I am using right now has an ATmega32U4, USB port, and 16 I/O pins. I am using LUFA for a USB stack.

I know that I can get 8*8=64 inputs from the 16 I/O pins by creating a grid and strobing over it, but I am concerned how long this will take to complete and if it may affect the USB connection because of the delays. (I realize that strobing through 64 I/O values probably won't take that long, but I plan on putting some additional processing in that will slow things down further.)

My plan was to create a timer interrupt and use the interrupt to call the HID_Device_USBTask() and USB_USBTask() functions. Does this sound reasonable or is there a better approach I could take?

Comment: If you are concerned about the time between calling the tasks you can call it multiple times during the scanning/processing. Calling those functions inside a timer ISR may be asking for trouble.

Comment: "Calling those functions inside a timer ISR may be asking for trouble." Why? I don't understand them well enough to know why this isn't a good idea.

Comment: It could interfere with something else more-or-less randomly if everything is not re-entrant. You can set a flag in the timer ISR and use that as a decision point.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very reasonable, as long as you bear in mind that accessing the same data by the normal code and the interrupt code can cause trouble, if it happens at the same time.

Imagine, you have a buffer for sending data via USB, and a counter for the number of data bytes actually inside the buffer.

There are actually 10 bytes to be send in the buffer, so `counter`=10.

If your code wants to append three further bytes, it will:

1. Read `counter` to know at which position of the buffer the bytes have to be inserted
2. Write the bytes to positions 11, 12, 13
3. Increase `counter` by 3, as there are now three more bytes in the buffer.

The USB routine called later, will to this:

1. Read `counter` to know how many bytes have to be sent
2. Send that bytes
3. Set `counter` to zero

Now, if the USB routine is called by a timer interrupt, it is called while your normal function is executing a random line. For example, it may be called just after the normal function processed step 2. What happens?

- The normal routine has already written the new bytes to position 11, 12 and 13.
- The USB routine reads `counter`, which still is 10, and so sends just the first ten bytes in the buffer. After, it sets `counter` to zero.
- The normal routine continues where it was interrupted and increases `counter` by three. It is `counter`=3 !!!

The code does not only ignore the new three bytes. On the next call, the USB routine will send the first three bytes in the buffer, which are the same three bytes sent by the last call.

To circumvent this problem, just do all the button reading / data processing while the USB routine is called by the timer interrupt. As soon as you want to put data into the buffer, disable the interrupt/timer, write to the buffer and to `counter`, and enable the interrupt again.

The USB routine has to be called at least once within a given time interval. If your timing is too tight, it's possible you exceed the interval when disabling the interrupt. Therefore, call the USB routine manually directly after disabling the interrupt, or choose a much shorter period for your timer.